# Same numerical code returns different output whether it is in C++ or C

Tags: c++, c, numerical, derivative, calculus

I was given an example C++ numerical code calculating derivatives in three different ways. I have to convert it to C. I thought it wouldn't give me any problems due to original using cmath anyway, but I was so wrong.  Here is the original code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


double metoda_pochodna_1(int x, double h)
{
    return (sin(x+h) - sin(x)) / h;
}   
double metoda_pochodna_2(int x, double h)
{
    return (sin(x+(0.5*h)) - sin(x-(0.5*h))) / h;
}
double metoda_pochodna_3(int x, double h)
{
    return ((sin(x-2*h) - 8*sin(x-h) + 8*sin(x+h) - sin(x+2*h)) / (12*h));
}


int main()
{
    double h, w1, w2, w3, kos = cos(1.0);
    int x=1;
    ofstream wyniki;
    wyniki.open("wyniki.dat");

    for (h = pow(10.0, -15.0); h < 1; h *= 1.01) 
    {
        w1 = log10(abs(metoda_pochodna_1(x,h) - kos));
        w2 = log10(abs(metoda_pochodna_2(x,h) - kos));
        w3 = log10(abs(metoda_pochodna_3(x,h) - kos));
        wyniki << log10(h)<<"  "<< w1 <<"  "<< w2 <<"  "<< w3 << "\n";
        cout << log10(h)<<"  "<< w1 <<"  "<< w2 <<"  "<< w3 << "\n";
    }

    wyniki.close();
    cout << endl;
    /*system("pause");*/ //uruchamiane z windowsa
    return 0;
}
```

And here is my C version; I just changed file handling. NOTE: I changed to `long double` during troubleshooting , but the resulting output is exactly the same as the version using regular `double`.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



long double metoda_pochodna_1(int x,long  double h)
{
    return (sin(x+h) - sin(x)) / h;
}   
long double metoda_pochodna_2(int x,long  double h)
{
    return (sin(x+(0.5*h)) - sin(x-(0.5*h))) / h;
}
long double metoda_pochodna_3(int x, long double h)
{
    return ((sin(x-2*h) - 8*sin(x-h) + 8*sin(x+h) - sin(x+2*h)) / (12*h));
}


int main()
{
    long double h, w1, w2, w3, kos = cos(1.0);
    int x=1;
    FILE * file;
    file = fopen("wyniki.dat","w+");


    for (h = pow(10.0, -15.0); h < 1; h *= 1.01) 
    {
        w1 = log10(abs(metoda_pochodna_1(x,h) - kos));
        w2 = log10(abs(metoda_pochodna_2(x,h) - kos));
        w3 = log10(abs(metoda_pochodna_3(x,h) - kos));
        fprintf(file,"%f %Lf %Lf %Lf\n",log10(h), w1,w2,w3);
        printf("%f %Lf %Lf %Lf\n",log10(h), w1,w2,w3);
        //wyniki << log10(h)<<"  "<< w1 <<"  "<< w2 <<"  "<< w3 << "\n";
        //cout << log10(h)<<"  "<< w1 <<"  "<< w2 <<"  "<< w3 << "\n";
    }

    fclose(file);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output of the C++ code, which I am assuming correct:

> ```
> -15  -1.82947  -1.82947  -1.28553
>
> -14.9957  -2.03091  -2.03091  -1.33768
>
> 14.9914  -2.41214  -2.41214  -1.39632
>
> -14.987  -2.81915  -2.81915  -1.46341
> ```
>
> [...]

And this is the output of the C version, which obviously differs (additional precision in front row is from `long double`, but the other three columns are all `-inf` regardless of whether `double` or `long double` is used):

> ```
> -15.000000 -inf -inf -inf
>
> -14.995679 -inf -inf -inf
>
> -14.991357 -inf -inf -inf
>
> -14.987036 -inf -inf -inf
> ```
>
> [...]

What is wrong with my converted code?

Comment: I notice the values printed as `-inf` were the output of the `%Lf` format specifier. Have you tried a simple test output of known values (that are not computed)?

Comment: So why do you think the **different** languages C and C++ should behave identical? And see what [mcve] means!

Comment: In C `abs` is an *integer* function. Use `fabs`.

Comment: SOLVED: Using fabs() instead of abs() makes everything ok. Thanks!

I provided test known values where I used %Lf specifier and they showed up correctly. It is not an issue of outputting data. %Lf is correct for POSIX system when outputting long double using printf and fprintf.

I know C and C++ are different languages but in such simple calculations  using same cmath library it would at least weird to NOT get the same results...

Comment: `abs()` is not part of the C math library (though `fabs()` is).  `abs()` is declared in `stdlib.h`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `abs` which is an integer function. The C floating point function is `fabs`.
After changing your three lines to

```
w1 = log10(fabs(metoda_pochodna_1(x,h) - kos));
w2 = log10(fabs(metoda_pochodna_2(x,h) - kos));
w3 = log10(fabs(metoda_pochodna_3(x,h) - kos));
```

the program outputs more sensible values.

Comment: That solved it! Values now are in check. Thank you very much.